# SQL: Can't understand how to select from my tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with a data extraction. I'm an sql noob and I think I have a serious issue with my data design skills. DB system is MYSQL running on Linux.

Table A is structured like this one:

```
TYPE    SUBTYPE ID
-------------------
xyz     aaa     0001
xyz     aab     0001
xyz     aac     0001
xyz     aad     0001
xyz     aaa     0002
xyz     aaj     0002
xyz     aac     0002
xyz     aav     0002
```

Table B is:

```
TYPE1   SUBTYPE1    TYPE2   SUBTYPE2    
-------------------------------------
xyz     aaa         xyz     aab
xyz     aac         xyz     aad
```

Looking at whole table A, I need to extract all rows where both type and subtype are present as columns in a single table B row. Of course this condition is never met since A.subtype can't be at same time equal to B.subtype1 AND B.subtype2 ...

In the example the result set for id should be:

```
xyz     aaa     0001
xyz     aab     0001
xyz     aac     0001
xyz     aad     0001
```

I m trying to use a join with 2 AND conditions, but of course I got an empty set.

EDIT:

@Barmar thank you for your support. It seems that I m really near the final solution. Just to keep things clear, I opened this thread with a shortened and simplified data structure, just to highlight the point where I was stuck.
I thought about your solution, and is acceptable to have both result on a single row. Now, I need to reduce execution time.

First join takes about 2 minutes to complete, and it produce around 23Million of rows. The second join (table B) is probably taking longer.
In fact, I need 3 hours to have the final set of 10 millions of rows. How can we impove things a bit? I noticed that mysql engine is not threaded, and the query is only using a single CPU. I indexed all fields used by join, but I m not sure its the right thing to do...since I m not a DBA 
I suppose also having to rely on VARCHAR comparison for such a big join is not the best solution. Probably I should rewrite things using numerical ID that should be faster..

Probably split things into different query will help parallelism. thanks for a feedback

Comment: Do you mean you need to find pairs of rows in Table A where one of them matches type1/subtype1 and the other one matches type2/subtype2, and then return both of those rows?

Comment: Can you also add the code you tried?

Comment: @Barmar: Exactly !

Comment: Make sure your index on table B is a composite index on all 4 columns, not separate indexes on each column. `CREATE INDEX types ON TableB (type1, subtype1, type2, subtype2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join Table A with itself to find all combinations of types and subtypes with the same ID, then compare them with the values in Table B.

```
SELECT t1.type AS type1, t1.subtype AS subtype1, t2.type AS type2, t2.subtype AS subtype2, t1.id
FROM TableA AS t1
JOIN TableA AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND NOT (t1.type = t2.type AND t1.subtype = t2.subtype)
JOIN TableB AS b ON t1.type = b.type1 AND t1.subtype = b.subtype1 AND t2.type = b.type2 AND t2.subtype = b.subtype2
```

This returns the two rows from Table A as a single row in the result, rather than as separate rows, I hope that's OK. If you need to split them up, you can move this into a subquery and join it back with the original table A to return each row.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TableA AS a
JOIN (the above query) AS x
ON a.id = x.id AND
    ((a.type = x.type1 AND a.subtype = x.subtype1)
    OR
     (a.type = x.type2 AND a.subtype = x.subtype2))
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00d407/4)

Comment: Barmar this is near what I would like to achieve. As you wrote, if I try to use "select * " I m receiving data from 3 tables on a single row..

Comment: Like I said, you just have to join it back with the original table. I've added that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TableA a
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM TableB b
    WHERE
        (b.Type1 = a.Type AND b.SubType1 = a.SubType)
        OR (b.Type2 = a.Type AND b.SubType2 = a.SubType)
)
AND a.ID = '0001'
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1beb45/1/0)</kbd>

Comment: I got a set of 60000 records after 10 mintes..seems good..at least I got a set..Is this query also checking that data from tab B is all present also in table  A?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Join like this :

```
Select A.Type, A.SubType, A.ID from a_table A JOIN b_table B
ON (A.Type = B.Type1 AND A.SubType = B.SubType1) OR
   (A.Type = B.Type2 AND A.SubType = B.SubType2)
```

But I think there is a problem in your design, you have same values in Table A with different ID and there is no any condition on ID !

Instead of storing Type and SubType in Table B, you can store an unique ID of each record of Table A to Table B, then you can think about better ways to get results you want ...

**Edit** :

With UNION of two joins you can get that result :

```
Select A.Type, A.SubType, A.ID from A_table A
JOIN b_table B1 ON A.Type = B1.Type1 AND A.SubType = B1.SubType1
WHERE (B1.Type2, B1.SubType2) IN (SELECT Type, SubType FROM A_table) AND ID = '0001'

UNION

Select A.Type, A.SubType, A.ID from A_table A
JOIN b_table B2 ON A.Type = B2.Type2 AND A.SubType = B2.SubType2
WHERE (B2.Type1, B2.SubType1) IN (SELECT Type, SubType FROM A_table) AND ID = '0001'
```

But as I say, I think there is a design problem, it seems better that each type and subtype have an unique ID in Table A and work with this ID on Table B

Comment: The OR clause is not good for my conditions..I need to be sure that type/subtype data in table B, are present both also in table A. I need at least 2 record, only 1 is not ok

Comment: @rayrick : you can be sure that types have found in Table B are present in Table A, because it have checked with AND clause; If you want that type1 and type2 both be present in Table A, the conditions should change a little ( I will Edit answer ), but the problem is on field ID, with no condition on ID you will get same records with different ID in the result

Comment: This is also near what I would to achieve..But I cannot accept a set of results where data is returing only from 1 select. I need to be sure both are returning at least 1 row. If this is not the case, I had to have an empty set